# Foreach HTML Element into javascript-array

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, foreach

At my webpage I have 3 select buttons with the name "Seizoen". I want to know which are selected and get the value as array back in my webpage.

At this moment I have this code:

```
var seizoen_array = $.each($(form).children("input.selected[name=seizoen]"), function(index, evt) {
   if(typeof(seizoen)=="undefined") { var seizoen = []; }
   seizoen[index] = $(evt).val();                                   
});
alert(seizoen);
alert(seizoen_array);
```

But that didn't work, because the variables in the loop can't displayed after the loop.
I searched a lot, but couldn't find a solution. Can some help me? ;-)

** Sorry for my bad English, I hope it is clear enough to understand...

Comment: Is there any particular reason the name of the array has been obfuscated? Looks an awful lot like "size one" to me

Comment: @AndrueAnderson: or it could just be Dutch for "season" perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest, using jQuery:

```
// this selects the <input> elements, with the class-name of
// 'selected' and the name of 'seizon', from within the <form>
// and then uses the map() method to form a map:
var seizoen_array = $('form input.selected[name=seizon]').map(function () {
    // returning the value of the current element of the collection
    // over which we're iterating to the map:
    return this.value;
// using get() to convert the map to an array:
}).get();
```

Or, with plain JavaScript:

```
// selects the <input> elements, with the class-name of
// 'selected' and the name of 'seizoen' to form a
// collection:
var seizoenElements = document.querySelectorAll('input.selected[name=seizoen]'),

// converts the collection to an Array (using Array.from()),
// iterates over that array of elements to form a new Array
// using Array.prototype.map() to return a new Array from the
// original:
    seizoen_array = Array.from(seizoenElements).map(function(el) {

        // if there is a value and the trimmed value has a
        // non-zero length:
        if (el.value && el.value.trim().length) {

            // returns the value to the new Array if
            // the above conditions are met:
            return el.value;
        }
    });
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- jQuery:

  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Comment: Could alternatively use `$.map()` on `$("form input.selected[name=seizon]")` and remove call to `.get()`

Answer (score 0):

You should look up how variable scoping works in JavaScript.  If you want the variable to be accessible outside the function, then you'll need to define it outside the function.  For example:

```
var seizoen = [];
var seizoen_array = $.each($(form).children("input.selected[name=seizoen]"), function(index, evt) {
   seizoen[index] = $(evt).val();                                   
});
alert(seizoen);
alert(seizoen_array);
```

Doing this to demonstrate how the variable scoping works, but you should use David's answer as it is better form.

Answer (score 0):

You put the selected elements before the `each()` method.  Also, I'm not sure if the nested array is what you really want but I think this is the output you want (maybe).

```
var seizoen_array = [];
$(form).children("input.selected[name=seizoen]").each( function(index, evt) {
   if(typeof seizoen =="undefined"){
      var seizoen = [];
   }
   seizoen[index] = $(this).val(); 
   seizoen_array.push(seizoen);                          
});
alert(seizoen);
alert(seizoen_array);
```